# New-AzureADMSInvitation fails for Service Principal with Company Administrator permission

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to invite a guest user to my Azure AD tenant using a Service Principal from a Multi-Tenant App. The app has been assigned `Company Administrator` in the directory. However when I call `New-AzureADMSInvitation` it errors out:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $AzureTenantId -ApplicationId  $AppId -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbprint

New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserDisplayName "Test User"  -InvitedUserEmailAddress "testuser@gmail.com" -InviteRedirectURL https://foo.bar.com -SendInvitationMessage $true
```

```
New-AzureADMSInvitation : Error occurred while executing NewAzureADMSInvitation 
Code: Unauthorized
Message: Insufficient privileges to perform requested operation by the application '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. 
ControllerName=MSGraphInviteAPI, ActionName=CreateInvite, URL absolute path=/api/xxxxx/invites
InnerError:
  RequestId: b44feabd-d731-4fb6-a115-1a1d0e09ba10
  DateTimeStamp: Mon, 22 Apr 2019 23:14:47 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Unauthorized
HttpStatusDescription: Unauthorized
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserDisplayName "Test User"  -I ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADMSInvitation], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphV10.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphV10.PowerShell.NewAzureADMSInvitation
```

[image: Here are my apps permissions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question has an interesting answer.

This issue is caused by `New-AzureADMSInvitation` invoking MS Graph API in the backend. NOT AAD Graph API

Functions in AAD Powershell actually invoke APIs in backend. If you capture a fiddler trace you will see the HTTPS trace used by the AAD Powershell.

Generally, AAD Powershell just invokes AAD Graph API only. However, `New-AzureADMSInvitation` invoke this MS Graph API in the backend:

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/invitations`

You can see this command includes ***MS***, it means that it invokes MS Graph actually.

**Solution:**

As you're using service principal to connect AAD, the AAD Powershell will obtain an access_token with application permissions. So, please to to Azure Portal > App registration > Find your app > Settings > Required Permissions > Add Microsoft Graph API > Select `Directory.ReadWrite.All` in **Application Permission**. Please also remember to click  `Grant Permissions` button to consent the permissions.

Re-connect the AAD Powershell and have a try.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, i tried the steps you mentioned and I still get the same error. I tried in both the home tenant and external tenant of the app.

Comment: Hi @MichaelSabin May I know have you clicked "Grant Permissions" button after added `Directory.ReadWrite.All` in `Application Permission`?

Comment: Added image of permissions

Comment: You need to add Application Permissions, NOT Delegated permissions as you're using service principal to login AAD.